# How to move a window of the bottom panel in Gnome 3

Tags: gnome3, panel

I am using Debian 8 Jessie with Gnome 3.
I can't move the windows of the bottom panel. I just want to rearranged them but it doesn't work.
I click one of them and try to move it but nothing happend.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The tabs work in a chronological order of opening and active and let's say you have 4 applications 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D' launched in the same order. Gnome3 will display this as A-B-C-D.

Now if you access B again, the order of recently active changes and will change to A-C-D-B. To see this in action now, follow the steps below:

Press `Alt` + `F2` and then type `r`, press `enter`.

Again to stress that this works purely chronologically, let the tabs which are alphabetically chosen as above be arranged on your panel as D-B-A-C and now you want them to be arranged as A-B-C-D. So maximise/open the apps in the same order (i.e. A-B-C-D) and

Press `Alt` + `F2` and then type `r`, press `enter`.

Unfortunately, with classic Gnome 3 the feature you're looking for is still not available.

To stick to the old feature of just dragging the tabs across, you might want to install an extension from https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/898/mmod-panel/
and switch off the window-list extension.

Comment: How can I change this feature? I want the old feature that let me arrange them just clicking on a tab and move it

Comment: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=702601